# Access to different instances of service provided in component (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, frameworks

I have datapickerComponent with datapickerService (provided in datapickerComponent, so new
instances of datapickerComponent will create instances of datapickerService).
How I can access to different instances of datapickerService?
I create on my TestComponent two datapickerComponent (datapickerComponent1, datapickerComponent2).
I want get in my TestComponent something like this:

```
constructor(datapickerService1: DatapickerService,
            datapickerService2: DatapickerService){}
```

I mean that I want to manage the data independently of each other...
So I have two tables on one page(with datePickers). And i want that change date of one datepicker not affected to another(I achieved this with a provide DatapickerService to DatapickerComponent) and i want to get this data(from two datepickers) to my TestComponent

Comment: what do you mean by access to different instances of datapickerService?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale 
I mean that I want to manage the data independently of each other.

Comment: Just create two properties on your component, they will both hold different data

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn i know that i can create 2 ViewChild variable. But I looking for better answer...